# How do I apply a required field validation only if one radio button is selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I'm using MVC Data Anottation for client validations.

How do you implement this simple scenario:

Mark a field as required only if one radio button is selected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you wrote you're doing client side validation, so one way to accomplish your goal would be a simple javascript that would remove / modify validation rules attached to your input element:

```
$("#YourCheckBox").click(function(){ 
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $("#FirstName").rules("add","required")
  } else {
      $("#FirstName").rules("remove","required")
  }
});
```

you can find out more about validation plugin and its features here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules

Of course you can easily find out more about jquery unobutrusive validation and do your variant. Thing to remember though is that you want to keep your client-side and backend validation consistent, so if you strip the [Required] from the model, you would have to check the value in your save/edit method.

Comment: humm I kind of like that, will give that a try

Comment: I tried that approach but i didnt work, it seems that there is a validation metadata variable somewhere in the DOM that get created when the form is loaded and has all the information regarding the validations of the fields on the form so I can modify the that-val to false even I can remove it and it doesnt enable or disable the validation for that field

Comment: it seems that this doesnt work when the element are hidden. In my case I have the required element in a tab and when another tab is selected and I click on save the validation of that element doesnt work, is skipping it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at using [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) there is a RequiredIf attribute

```
private class Person
{
  [Required]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  public bool Married { get; set; }

  [RequiredIfTrue("Married")]
  public string MaidenName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This looks really good but I prefer to don't add that to my project, this is one single scenario.

Comment: Have a look at the source code and it'll give you an idea of how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here, this should point you in the right direction.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As you did not post any code, i'm assuming your radio button field has the id `rdbRequired` and your field name say `MyField`.

Initially mark `MyField` as required.

Then in your controller, write like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
       // If the radio button is not selected, MyField is marked as not required. I mean it is not validated
       if (model.rdbRequired == false)  
       {
            ModelState.Remove("MyField"); 
       }
       if(ModelState.IsValid){
       //do something
       }
       else{
             return View(model);
       }
    }
```

Hope this helps you